# Redirect URL folder/directory in Joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, server

I changed the "Alias" of a Joomla menu from

> нови-електромотори/

to just

> нови/

How can I redirect the old URLs containing "нови-електромотори/" and fetched by Google to "нови/"?

I tried with this, but it did not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^нови-електромотори/?$ $1/нови/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Also tried with Joomla redirect managed, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_alias is even easier:

```
Redirect 301 /old /new
```

But if you have rewrite rules in your htaccess file already, then you need to stick with using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,R=301]
```